# Direction and amount of current flow in the the circuit?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current

In the below electrical circuit if the wire CD has resistance 1 micro-ohm and the bulb has resistance 2 ohm and all other wires have negligible resistance will any current pass through the bulb or the whole current will travel through ADCB ?
In my opinion, maximum of the current will flow through CD but still a small current will flow through the bulb. Please correct me.
[image]

Comment: You're already asking about circuits including BJTs, so I'm pretty sure you don't need us to check your homework guess. You can even calculate the exact result yourself. If not, show us how far you've come at calculating it, and ask us about the one thing you've acutely got stuck.

Comment: What does your circuit simulator tell you about this scenario? How about trying to set up and solve the circuit equations describing the node voltages and branch currents in this circuit?

Comment: 1 uOhm is a pretty good short circuit

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 thanks for that but now if I increase the resistance comparable to the resistance of the bulb(1 ohm) will now current flow equally in CD as in bulb?

Comment: @soumyadip_poddar It's clear from inspection that the bulb and CD resistor experience the same voltage applied across them. What does Ohm's law tell you about their currents if a) the resistances are very different and b) the resistances are the same?

Comment: I suggest that you redraw the circuit in the conventional manner. Stand the power source upright on the left. Replace wire CD with a resistor of 1 µΩ. Replace the bulb with a 2 Ω resistor. Join the two ground points. Now what current flows in each resistor?

Comment: Recommendation: if you want to specify that a wire has resistance, draw it as a resistor. Schematic wires have zero resistance, by convention.

Comment: The issue isn't "sounding intellectual", but rather that there wasn't really an attempt to develop your own solution. If you show what you tried, we can write an answer that explains the gaps and covers any misconceptions. If you don't, all we can do is provide the same thing that a circuit simulator could already tell you.

Comment: @nanofarad I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume "ideal" components throughout, except for wire CD, then the 5V supply will deliver 5V.  All the grounds are assumed connected together, so 5/2 = 2.5A will flow through the lamp.

Meanwhile, 5 mega-amps will flow through wire CD.  It will get rather hot, dissipating 25 megawatts of heat.

There's a point at which "ideal" circuits don't really make sense.  This is one of them.

Comment: Maybe it won't get that hot. Maybe the 1 uOhm resistor is mounted on a heatsink with 1 degree C / MW thermal resistance to ambient.